# MVVM Multiple ViewModels Communication via Serial Port/USB

Tags: c#, mvvm, serial-port, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I have to develop an Application, that will communicate with an external device, connected via Serial Port/USB.

Here is the diagram of the basic UI:

[UI Diagram Concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLWPm.png)

There is a MainWindow(View) and MainWindowViewModel.

On the left, there is a **list of sub-views (with checkbox)**, and on the right, there is a content control (or page etc which ever appropriate). Upon selecting the appropriate Subview, its respective Subview will be shown. Each Subview contains configuration options (in form of Radio, Checkbox, Dropdown etc).
The User will configure the options, as per the requirements, and then finally click on the **Read** Button (which is the part of MainWindow).
And after the Read Button is pressed, communication with the serial port/USB will start based on the selected sub-views.

What is the Best Possible Approach to design such an Application ?

1. Each Sub-view will have its own ViewModel (with Properties bound with respective view), which will communicate with Serial Port independently of each other. In this case how will the **state machine** be handled because there is only one allowed connection with serial port at a time ?
2. All the Options will be read by, MainWindowViewModel, and it will start the communication, and fill up all the data in subviews. (This will result in a huge 
   ViewModel, because there are a lot of Options/Settings to tackle for each of the sub-views)
3. Any other approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Have one class separate from view models that would communicate and use the MvvmLight NotificationMessage class to send data to, and receive from that class.